# Is `cargo clippy` a superset of `cargo check`?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to build and test my Rust code with a CI, and I'm wondering whether `cargo clippy` (potentially with options) covers everything that `cargo check` does. Do I only need to run `cargo clippy`, or do I need to run both?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[`clippy` itself runs `cargo check`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/blob/c154754b74577906c5d55d57f7daeff02d6a33e7/src/main.rs#L59).

Comment: Does this mean it doesn't run **anything** else but `cargo check`? (No.)

Comment: think it effectively proves that `cargo clippy` *is* a superset of `cargo check`.